# Can I add an ORDER BY clause on a query with an UNION clause in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Imagine I have the following table with the following data already inserted in it:

Table Person

```
id_person          name         age
------------------------------------------
    1              name1        18
    2              name2        37
    3              name3        23
```

Now imagine I want to execute a query that shows the persons older than 30 and persons younger than 20 and I want to use an `UNION` clause, like this:

```
select name, age from person
where age >= 30
UNION
select name, age from person
where age <= 20;
```

The output this query would give would be:

```
   name      age
-------------------
   name2      37
   name1      18
```

But what if I want to order the output using an `order by` clause?
Where should I write the clause?

Would any of the following queries work?

```
select name, age from person
where age >= 30
group by name
order by age asc
UNION
select name, age from person
where age <= 20;
```

...

```
select name, age from person
where age >= 30
UNION
select name, age from person
where age <= 20
group by name
order by age asc;
```

Comment: Why not install MySQL, and see?

Comment: Your queries are malformed.  You have a `group by` but unaggregated columns in the `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last query (although `age` is ambiguous in the select list since it is not included in the group by clause):

```
select name, age from person
where age >= 30
UNION
select name, age from person
where age <= 20
group by name
order by age asc;
```

is the same as:

```
(select name, age from person
where age >= 30)
UNION
(select name, age from person
where age <= 20
group by name)
order by age asc;
```

as it is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

> A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized...

So the `order by` clause affects the result of the `UNION`.  
Also it is important to know that:

> Use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about
>   the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION
>   by default produces an unordered set of rows

so don't use `ORDER BY` in neither of the 2 queries (if you don't want to set a `LIMIT` also), but use one at the end for the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are malformed -- columns in the a `group by` query that are neither keys or aggregated.  However, the general idea in MySQL is to use parentheses:

```
(<query 1>)
union all
(<query 2>)
order by <whatever>
```

Your particular query can be written as:

```
select name, age
from person
where age >= 30 or age <= 20
order by age asc;
```